# How to get rid of option index in Nintex Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, nintex-workflow

I have created SharePoint list with unique codes: A, B, C

Then I have created Nintex Form and added list lookup to get those codes as a dropdown menu, and added one label.

I have form rule that captures whatever selected from dropdown menu to variable. When I print out variable in label, it does not show only A, B or C but instead shows 1#A etc

Can someone answer please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Nintex support if you’re still facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

try this
var dropDownValue = NWF.RuntimeFunctions.parseLookup(NWF$('#'+yourField).val(),true);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).